# How to import csv file based on date in python? The file path is absolute

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I'm trying to figure out how I can import a file in python just by having a hint of the file name in an absolute path

example: if I have a route home/Download/ ==> this is the route
In this route I have CSV files that I download for data processing and I eliminate all the other csv files that I have to only leave the most recent csv file. The question is:
How can I read that file with the script without having to go back to the script and change the name of the file within the script or change the name of the file in the path.

the hint is that the files are always downloaded in the same format
example: filename-date.csv

what varies in the name is always the date section but the file name is always the same and with the same .csv extension

So far this is what I have of the script

but I need to automate how the script chooses the file, since the name of the file that I want to process is always changing, but the track is always the same as I said before

[image of the code that I am implementing so far but I got stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxAir.png)

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}`) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer below. dir_path will have your directory(home/Download/) and date_var will have the date which file will be having.

```
import glob
for f in glob(dir_path+'*date_var.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

If you are not sure about the date and wanted to go with latest file in that directory then you can use below logic.

```
import glob
import os

files_list= glob.glob(dir_path+'*.csv') 
latest_file = max(files_list, key=os.path.getctime)
```